# OR search by unfixed number of keywords by Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I am fetching data by string searching

For example ) "ski" "tennis" OR search. I can fetch the data like this.

```
$articles  = $em->createQuery(
    "SELECT a FROM AcmeTopBundle:ArticleData a
    where a.title like :keyword OR a.title like :keyword2
    order by a.createdAt DESC")
->setParameters(array('keyword' => 'ski','keyword2' => 'tennis'))
->getResult();
```

If I can tell how many keywords I need , it works well.

(in this case 2 keywords,but what if 3 keywords?)

Howvever ,if I can't tell the number of keywords beforehand,

How can I solve it?

Is there good way for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested).

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('a')
   ->from('AcmeTopBundle:ArticleData a')
   ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC');

foreach ($keywords as $i => $keyword) {
    $qb->orWhere('a.title LIKE ?' . $i)->setParameter($i, $keyword);
}

$articles = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```